# Is there a way to get Tmux ID of the session into a python program running in that session?

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables, tmux

I just wanted to to know if it is possible to run a python script in a tmux session and get its ID - like if I have a tmux session id: 1, I want to run a python program where one of it's variable should be the ID of the tmux session it is running in, In this case 1.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111499/how-do-i-know-the-name-of-a-tmux-session

Answer (score 0):

Found it. In it is available in environment variables under key "TMUX" as /tmp//tmux-1000/default,4795,0. Where the last digit is the tmux_id in my case.

```
tmux_id = os.environ["TMUX"][-1]
```

This is what I am using for now, but obviously there is a better way to split the string to get the ID.